# How can I upload colour attribute options using CSV in Magento?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I want to upload colour attribute options from a CSV file with visual swatch value. I have to import colour code for the visual swatch.

Kindly Help me!

Comment: you need to provide some more information so that we can understand exactly what you want to achieve and you need to specify the version of Magento you are using.

Answer (score 0):

you can use product import csv and add custom option in it
as last column 
here i attchaed my csv code 
as in screenshort

[product_import.csv](https://prnt.sc/qttu0z)

and my csv is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s63rTEZOaF-3HSk3dX61ZfQ_vMUhz1cH/view?usp=sharing check it out it works with me